# Space length between the chapter number and the chapter title

Tags: spacing, sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters

How can I learn the horizontal distance between the chapter number and the chapter title both in *ToC*  and the body text where I use `\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{book}`. Which keys hold these values?

Answer (score 5):

[`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) (like [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls)) sets the ToC entry for a chapter using `\l@chapter`. This is what it looks like:

```
\newcommand*\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
```

The specific thing to note here is the value of `\@tempdima`, set to `1.5em`. The first argument of `\l@chapter` (or `#1`) uses `\numberline`, which is defined in the kernel [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) as:

```
\def\numberline#1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{#1\hfil}}
```

creating a box of width `\@tempdima` and left-aligning its contents. Note that this `1.5em` is based on the prevailing font at the time of setting (`\normalsize\bfseries` by default).

---

The (numbered) chapter head in `book` (and `report`) is set via the macro `\@makechapterhead`. Here's a take on that:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

The space between the word `Chapter` (or `\@chapapp` in the definition above) and the number (`\thechapter` in the definition above) is a regular `\space` or `\`.

---

In both instances, if you want to change these defaults, you have at least 3 options:

1. Use a package that allows you to modify this content (like [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) or the like);
2. Copy the entire definition and change it to your liking (making `\newcommand` -> `\renewcommand`);
3. Use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch the command. For example,

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\l@chapter}% <cmd>
     {1.5em}% <search>
     {5.5em}% <replace>
     {}{}% <success><failure>
   \makeatother
   ```

   would use a `5.5em` wide box for setting the chapter number in the ToC, increasing the gap between the number and title. Also

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
   \makeatletter
   \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
     {\space}% <search>
     {\hspace*{100pt}\ignorespaces}% <replace>
     {}{}% <success><failure>
   \makeatother
   ```

   would insert a `100pt` gap between the word `Chapter` (or whatever `\@chapapp` is) and the number. `\ignorespaces` would just remove any trailing spaces left inside the original definition of `\@makechapterhead`.