# Bad TOC entries spacing for chapter 10 and beyond

Tags: table-of-contents, book-design

When making long documents under `book` class if one needs 10 or more chapters, something weird happens with the table of contents: the space between the number of the chapter and its title disappears, just like it was trying to preserve a beautiful alignment on the left but leading to an incorrect output.

[image]

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[spanish, 12pt]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}
\newpage
\chapter{B}
\newpage
\chapter{C}
\newpage
\chapter{D}
\newpage
\chapter{E}
\newpage
\chapter{F}
\newpage
\chapter{G}
\newpage
\chapter{H}
\newpage
\chapter{I}
\newpage
\chapter{J}
\newpage
\chapter{K}
\end{document}
```

To be honest, I have no idea how to fix this. I hope you guys do.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I can confirm the behaviour you described!

Comment: The space allocated for the chapter number width is `1.5em` by default. You can adjust that to your liking by following the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch suggested in [Space length between the chapter number and the chapter title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88025/5764).

Comment: NB: the command `\newpage` is redundant here, as the book chapters start on the right side as default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`tocloft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package to adjust the spacing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{2em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A}\chapter{B}\chapter{C}\chapter{D}
\chapter{E}\chapter{F}\chapter{G}\chapter{H}
\chapter{I}\chapter{J}\chapter{K}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I usually advise to call the package as `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` in order to avoid a certain (not so nice) feature.