# Reduce the spacing after reference to chapter

Tags: spacing, cross-referencing

Reference to a section is not problematic but referencing to a chapter produces some strange spacing after the number of chapter. See attached picture:

[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,fleqn,openright]{book}

% use quite a lot of packages
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsmath,bm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage[inner=30mm,
            outer=25mm,
            top=30mm,
            bottom=25mm]{geometry}

% paragraph settings
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.5ex}

% set equation environment indentation
\setlength{\mathindent}{0.5cm}%

% set itemize environment whitespacing and left margin
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,nolistsep, leftmargin=*}

% set table and figure captions
\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt,singlelinecheck=false}
\captionsetup[figure]{justification=centering}

% set tablename to Preglednica
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{Preglednica}
}

% command for multiline cell in table
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}


% set section and tableofcontents depth
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\def\labelitemi{--}

%  accordingly format a chapter definition
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge\thechapter}

% set fancy_nohead fancy header
\fancypagestyle{fancy_nohead}{
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\chead{}
\cfoot{}
}

% assign no_header
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{fancy_nohead}

% section and chapter formatting
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.\quad}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}\label{cha:test}
Something written here.
\chapter{New test}\label{cha:new_test}
Reference to Chapter \ref{cha:test} \nameref{cha:test}.
\end{document}
```

And one line has to be problematic because simply writing

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,fleqn,openright]{book}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}\label{cha:test}
Something written here.
\chapter{New test}\label{cha:new_test}
Reference to Chapter \ref{cha:test} \nameref{cha:test}.
\end{document}
```

is not problematic anymore.

Does anybody have an idea which of the packages is problematic or maybe knows a workaround?

Comment: You renew the `\thechapter` command to contain `\quad`. That's all. Remove that extra horizontal space and you're done.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The culprit is the instruction `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.\quad}` -- what is the purpose of this instruction, especially the `\quad` component?

Comment: @Mico I prefer the visual outcome of the Chapter. This should (and it does) produce a \quad spacing between the number of the Chapter and the name of the chapter. Example: `\chapter{Test}` is visible as *1.____Test*. But as @TeXnician found out this also corrupts my referencing. Is there a way to keep both - my spacing in the chapters and not destroy the reference to it?

Comment: As an aside, see [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764) Typically, [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) should be loaded last, and most definitely *after* sectioning and other reference packages (like [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) and [`caption`](//ctan.org/pkg/caption)). In some cases it's not necessary, but it's definitely preferred/advised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the way the `chapter` counter is represented is the issue here. That is, the line

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.\quad}
```

causes the extra space (a `\quad`) to be added to your reference. Most likely you've redefined `\thechapter` because you want some additional space between the chapter number and its title in the actual chapter heading. This can be achieved through your use of [`titlesec`](//ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)'s `\titleformat`:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\Huge\thechapter.\quad}
```

Also, since your other sectioning number redefinitions end in `.`, references to these will also include a period `.` in it, which is not ideal. Instead, redefine the *hierarchically* and *without* the trailing period. Rather add the trailing period as part of the sectioning display. One way is to redefine `\@seccntformat` (see [How to add a dot after the section number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24439/5764)):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

By hierarchically I mean using `\the...` for any parent counter in the subordinate counter representation:

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}
```

The above set of commands is somewhat superfluous, as this is the default for the `book` class anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have a `\quad` (which creates horizontal space) in your definition of `\thechapter`. Remove it and you're done. If you want to add some space within the chapter's line use `titlesec` or a similar package (or see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88025/124577)).

And the other lines renewing `\theX` commands should probably be replaced by a `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and then many `\counterwithin{X}{chapter}`.

Maybe you can also reconsider the usage of so many packages too. Probably you do not make use of all of them. Try removing the unnecessary ones. One example is `float` which only really serves to provide the `H` float option which should not be used (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370627/124577)).